# R plyr and break

Tags: r, plyr

How can I correctly instruct a plyr type command to break if a condition is met?

```
plyr::l_ply(1:10,function(x){
  print(x)
  if(x > 5) break
})

> Error in .fun(piece, ...) : no loop for break/next, jumping to top level
```

Comment: use return instead

Comment: Nope. Doesn't work, in the above, using return still results in all the numbers 1 to 10 being printed. I want the whole process to terminate when x > 5. Of course this is a trivial example, representative of a different problem I am working on.

Comment: oh. then youre using the wrong function

Answer (score 0):

I believe that `return` is the right way to go; it just have to be placed right.

```
plyr::l_ply(1:10,function(x){
  if(x > 5){
    return()
  }
  else{
    print(x)
  }
})
```

This gives:

```
[1] 1
[1] 2
[1] 3
[1] 4
[1] 5
```

Comment: Yeah I am aware of this, but it is still looping over all elements, what if the list was say 1:1e6, the purposes of breaking, is to shortcut the loop.

Comment: I see. So you want to find a first number that breaks your threshold and print all number until then?

Comment: I want to break, given a logical condition could be anything, pick a random number `if(runif(1) > 0.5)`, is the weather sunny today, does the pope touch up kids., it doesn't matter for the purposes of my question here: My real problem is nothing like this. I just need to break from a plyr call prematurely, given satisfaction of a logical condition.